# How can i get the current content size of webview?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, margin

**When i display the epub in uiwebview i can see that there are lines under 480 px so how can i limit the content size height to 450 px and add a bottom margine of 50px .currently iam adding a total padding by using following code i dont know how to limit content height of uiwebview ?**

```
NSString *padding = @"document.body.style.padding='15px 15px 15px 15px';";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:padding];
```

**please help me**

**i tried this code for getting content size but it returning a values of 14783**

`webView.scrollView.ContentSize.height;` then i get 14783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this on...

```
CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollWidth;"] floatValue],
                                [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] floatValue]);
```

Edited .......

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;

    frame.size.height = 5.0f;

    webView.frame = frame;
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGSize mWebViewTextSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];  // Pass about any size

    CGRect mWebViewFrame = webView.frame;


    mWebViewFrame.size.height = mWebViewTextSize.height;

    webView.frame = mWebViewFrame;


    //Disable bouncing in webview
    for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    {
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        {
            [subview setBounces:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can i print this by using float ?

Comment: Yes you can like this. NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", contentSize.width, contentSize.height);

Comment: i got this value  29975963932020441088.000000  as content size

Comment: is width or height tell me ?

Comment: You know its content size.Its not scroll's height.

Comment: one minut..my webview size is 480px in height and content size is 500  how?

Comment: you know if your content is more than 480 in that case you need to scroll your scrollview. So its not scrollview's height its content height. And read apple documentation of ScrollView that will be clear your concept.

Comment: currently iam getting 500 what is that?scrollview height? im getting this for every page even one line or two line

Comment: can i zoom in that 500px content to 480px?

Comment: Please see my edited answer to set your content size or uiwebview.

Comment: sorry its not working for me..now iam not able to see rest of the epub pages

Comment: Sorry for it please do accordting to u. You know i dont have enough time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1
{
      NSString  *totalHeight;

        totalHeight = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"foo\").offsetHeight;"];

         if([totalHeight intValue] >= 450)
         {
            [webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, webView.frame.size.width, 450)];
         }
         else
         {
          [webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, webView.frame.size.width, [totalHeight floatValue])];
         }
}
```

I hope it helps you.